# Launcher to launch a string of commands

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, launcher

I'm trying to make a custom launcher for Cairo Dock that, when clicked, open a terminal window and executes `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt autoremove` in succession.

So far, this is what I have:

`xterm -e sudo apt-get update && xterm -e sudo apt-get upgrade && xterm -e sudo apt autoremove`

With this, however, I have to enter my *long* password three times because it opens three separate terminal windows with each command. Running `xterm -e sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt autoremove` doesn't work because it's three separate commands and xterm doesn't know that I want **everything** after `-e` to be executed in the *same* terminal window.

Is there something other than `&&` that would define it all as one command rather than three? Will I have to write a script or something (I have no experience at all with scripts yet)?

I'm using Terminix to execute the original command.

Comment: Why not to put these three comands in a bash script and execute them by `sudo bash ~/updatesystem.sh`?

Comment: Or what about `sudo -i`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add some quotation marks:

```
xterm -e "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt autoremove"
```

I also like to add `sudo apt clean` to my update oneliner and I set an `alias` in my `~/.bash_aliases` file to execute the line with just the command `update`:

```
alias update='sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt clean'
```

Or if you want a separate `xterm`:

```
alias update='xterm -e "sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt clean"'
```

If you want your `xterm` to stay open after executing the commands, add `;bash` to the command chain's end or add the option `-hold` before `-e`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command this way:

```
xterm -e sudo bash -c "apt update && apt upgrade && apt autoremove"
```

with this you only will enter your password once.